# Issue to randomize the content of an Array type

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

I've got this code to randomize the content of an string array:

```
Public Function Randomize_Array(ByVal array() As String) As Array
    Return array.OrderBy(Function() Array_randomizer.Next).ToArray
End Function
```

The problem is I need to make an overload to randomize integer (or any other type of arrays), Important: I need to preserve the type of the array (I mean to don't turn an integer array to a string array when randomizing)

this is what I've tried:

```
Dim IntArray As Array = {1, 2, 3}
Randomize_Array(IntArray)

Dim Array_randomizer As New Random

' The Overload does not works
Public Function Randomize_Array(ByVal array As Array) As Array
    Return array.OrderBy(Function() Array_randomizer.Next).ToArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Public Function Randomize_Array(ByVal array As Array) As Array
    Return array.Cast(Of Object).OrderBy(Function() Array_randomizer.Next).ToArray
End Function
```

Or for a generic solution:

```
Public Function Randomize_Array(Of T)(ByVal array As T()) As T()
    Return array.OrderBy(Function() Array_randomizer.Next).ToArray
End Function
```

You might also be interested in the '[Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)' which shuffles the elements of the array in-place without creating a new array (and is therefore more efficient). It would look something like this:

```
Public Sub Shuffle(ByVal array As Array)
    Dim randomizer As New Random
    For i As Integer = array.Length To 1 Step -1
        Dim j As Integer = randomizer.Next(i)
        Dim tmp As Object = array(j)
        array(j) = array(i - 1)
        array(i - 1) = tmp
    Next
End Sub
```